# ASP.net when posting new entry everything is fine but when called afterwards, data is gone

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I have 2 classes: Game and Location.
The purpose of my API is that I can create a new game and within that game 2 random Locations from the database get added.

Game class:

```
public class Game
{
    public Game()
    {
        GameLocations = new List<Location>();
        GameSuspects = new List<Suspect>();
        GameClues = new List<Clue>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int GameId { get; set; }    
    public bool GameWon { get; set; }


    public ICollection<Location> GameLocations { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Suspect> GameSuspects { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Clue> GameClues { get; set; }

}
```

Location class:

```
public class Location
{
    public double LocLat { get; set; }
    public double LocLong { get; set; }
    public string LocDescription { get; set; }
    public string LocName { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<GameLocation> GameLocations { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int LocId { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I try to create a new game and add locations to it:

```
    [HttpPost("newgame")]
    public IActionResult CreateNewGame()
    {
        var newGame = new Game();

        // add random locations
        var location1 = _dbcontext.Locations.Find(1);
        var location2 = _dbcontext.Locations.Find(3);

        newGame.GameLocations.Add(location1);
        newGame.GameLocations.Add(location2);            

        //add suspects
        var suspect1 = _dbcontext.Suspects.Find(1);
        var suspect2 = _dbcontext.Suspects.Find(2);

        newGame.GameSuspects.Add(suspect1);
        newGame.GameSuspects.Add(suspect2);

        //add Clues
        var clue1 = _dbcontext.Clues.Find(1);
        var clue2 = _dbcontext.Clues.Find(2);

        newGame.GameClues.Add(clue1);
        newGame.GameClues.Add(clue2);

        _dbcontext.Games.Add(newGame);
        _dbcontext.SaveChanges();

        return Created("", newGame);
    }
```

and this is how I try to call the list of all created games:

```
    [HttpGet("getGames")]
    public ActionResult<List<Game>> GetGames()
    {
        return _dbcontext.Games.ToList();
    }
```

When I create a new game, everything seems fine. It returns me a game with new GameId and the Locations/Clues/Suspects seem to be added. But when I try to call them later on, the lists appear to be empty.
Am I doing something totally wrong with my creating or calling? Or is are my relations just totally messed up for what I'm trying to achieve, which is making a game that has random locations/suspects/clues from my database.

Comment: Have you tried including the related items like: `_dbcontext.Games.Include(g => g.GameLocations).Include(g => g.GameSuspects).Include(g => g.GameClues).ToList()`

Comment: That was the solution, now evrytime I create a new game, it removes the locations from the previous game. Any ideas why? :)

Comment: In what way do you mean? It deletes the entries from the db or the on screen values disappear?

Comment: I added my comment as the answer. I think that's where I should have put it in the first place.

Comment: Not sure if you missed my comment responding to your second questions as I added two at the same time? You still having problems with the locatings being removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `_dbcontext.Games.Include(g => g.GameLocations).Include(g => g.GameSuspects).Include(g => g.GameClues).ToList()` to include the related items.